# Añadir columna a dataframe con una media movil sobre los registros del mismo

Tags: python, pandas

Trabajo con Python 3.5 y con la libreria Pandas.

Tengo el siguiente dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'IdActivo': [1,2,3,3,2,1,3], 'Fecha' : ['2009-01-01','2009-02-01','2009-02-01','2009-03-01','2009-03-01','2009-03-01','2009-04-01'], 'Cierre' : [25.5,26.5,25.8,26.8,24.8,27.5,27.8]})

print(df.loc[:,['IdActivo','Fecha','Cierre']])
```

Al ejecutarlo obtengo el dataframe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues bien, necesito realizar el siguiente proceso:

1- Añadir una nueva columna llamada media móvil.

2- Que el valor de esa columna sea la media móvil de los dos registros anteriores para el idactivo de ese registro ordenador por fecha ascendente.

Realmente estoy intentando "traducir" un proceso que realizo en SQL Server con el uso de: `AVG OVER PARTITION BY IDACTIVO ORDER BY FECHA ASC`. Con lo que obtengo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por eso me pregunto de qué forma puedo llevar esto a cabo en Python.

¿alguna idea de cómo desarrollarlo?¿ qué conceptos o procesos debería investigar?

Muchas gracias

Angel

Comment: Si entiendo bien quieres, por ejemplo, que cuandi IdActivo es 1, ordene todas las filas que tengan ese IdActivo por fechas y saque la media de los dos valores anteriores a la fecha de la fila. ¿Es así o lo puede clarificar un poco mejor?

Comment: Si, asi es...el idactivo es un activo financiero que tengo en mi base de datos y con el cual he creado un dataframe. Basicamente, necesito obtener la media movil de sus cotizaciones. Al cargar varios idactivos distintos el cálculo de dicha media movil entiendo deberia localizar las cotizaciones anteriores para el idactivo en cuestion y calcularlas sobre ellas.  Como te comento en SQL se solventa con la clausula over partition by pero aqui no sé cómo desarrollarlo. Gracias

Comment: Que yo sepa, la funcionalidad Window SQL no está disponible de igual a igual en pandas pero se puede conseguir de alguna otra forma. Mira la respuesta a ver si te ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con Pandas puedes leer directamente de una base de datos usando SQL queries. Necesitarás el driver de la base de datos de turno.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries

Si ya tienes el dataframe se me ocurre una forma que no sé si será muy eficiente. Dejo el código y luego lo comento:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'IdActivo': [1,2,3,3,2,1,3], 
    'Fecha' : [
        '2009-01-01','2009-02-01','2009-02-01','2009-03-01',
        '2009-03-01','2009-03-01','2009-04-01'
    ], 
    'Cierre' : [25.5,26.5,25.8,26.8,24.8,27.5,27.8]
})

def mediarara(df):
    o = df.sort_values(by=['IdActivo', 'Fecha'])
    o['movil'] = o['Cierre'].rolling(2).mean()
    idx = o.iloc[1:]['IdActivo'].values != o.iloc[:len(o)-1]['IdActivo'].values
    idx = np.append([True], idx)
    o.loc[idx, 'movil'] = np.nan
    return o['movil'].sort_index()

df['movil'] = mediarara(df)

print(df)
```

En realidad, lo único que habría que comentar es la función `mediarara`. Línea a línea sería:

`o = df.sort_values(by=['IdActivo', 'Fecha'])` ordena por los valores de las columnas `IdActivo` y `Fecha`. El resultado sería:

```
   Cierre       Fecha  IdActivo
0    25.5  2009-01-01         1
5    27.5  2009-03-01         1
1    26.5  2009-02-01         2
4    24.8  2009-03-01         2
2    25.8  2009-02-01         3
3    26.8  2009-03-01         3
6    27.8  2009-04-01         3
```

`o['movil'] = o['Cierre'].rolling(2).mean()` esta línea crea una columna con los valores de la media de los dos últimos valores. Dependiendo de la versión de pandas quizá `rolling` no esté disponible y tengas que usar `rolling_mean`. El resultado es:

```
   Cierre       Fecha  IdActivo  movil
0    25.5  2009-01-01         1    NaN
5    27.5  2009-03-01         1  26.50
1    26.5  2009-02-01         2  27.00
4    24.8  2009-03-01         2  25.65
2    25.8  2009-02-01         3  25.30
3    26.8  2009-03-01         3  26.30
6    27.8  2009-04-01         3  27.30
```

Ya tenemos la columna con la media móvil pero nos sobran valores que no cumplen los requisitos.

`idx = o.iloc[1:]['IdActivo'].values != o.iloc[:len(o)-1]['IdActivo'].values` con esta línea veo cuando el `IdActivo` de mi línea y de la línea anterior NO son iguales devolviéndome un array de booleanos.

`idx = np.append([False], idx)` como la línea anterior me ha devuelto un array con `N-1` elementos le añado uno al principio con `True` ya que el primer elemento no tiene uno previo para promediar.

`o.loc[idx, 'movil'] = np.nan` igualo los valores de la columna `movil` que no cumplen a `NaN`.

Y finalmente devuelvo la columna `movil` ordenada por los índices originales.

Por tanto, el `df` ahora dispondría de una nueva columna y tendría la siguiente forma:

```
   Cierre       Fecha  IdActivo  movil
0    25.5  2009-01-01         1    NaN
1    26.5  2009-02-01         2    NaN
2    25.8  2009-02-01         3    NaN
3    26.8  2009-03-01         3  26.30
4    24.8  2009-03-01         2  25.65
5    27.5  2009-03-01         1  26.50
6    27.8  2009-04-01         3  27.30
```

Comment: La parte que no consigo entender del todo es aquella en la que haces idx = np.append([False], idx). Exactamente cuando comentas "como la línea anterior me ha devuelto un array con N-1 elementos le añado uno al principio con True"... Llevo un rato dándole vueltas y no lo capto. Y esta bien porque tu script por supuesto funciona correctamente con diferentes medias móviles.

Comment: En la siguiente línea, `o.loc[idx, 'movil'] = np.nan`, quiero usar el array de booleanos para rellenar con `NaN`s y para ello necesito que `idx` tenga `N` elementos. En la primera operación con `idx` solo tengo un array de `N-1` elementos por lo que para tener un array completo (`N` elementos) necesito añadir un valor más delante. No sé si ahora me explico mejor.

Comment: Si, ahora si lo he entendido. Tu explicación más la depuración del código que hice me ha hecho entenderlo. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Amigo deberías probar con el código:

```
df['MA2']=df['Cierre'].rolling(window=2).mean().shift(1)
```

El complemento `.rolling(window=NumeroDeMediasMoviles).mean()` logra obtener las medias móviles a partir del promedio de los dos datos anteriores, el shift es para poder mover un espacio la media y así la media móvil del periodo N será igual al promedio del periodo N-1 y N-2, sin esa parte del código sacaría el promedio del periodo N y N-1 para esa misma posición, así que con eso regulamos que las medias sean de los dos periodos anteriores.