# Crear un campo nuevo dentro de una tabla e introducirle el valor de otro pero cogiendo el valor de una fila anterior

Tags: python, pandas

Quisiera hacer lo siguiente:
Tengo una tabla con varios campos 'IdActivo,Fecha,Cierre' y quiero añadirle otro campo nuevo 'Cierre_1' el cual quiero introducir los valores que hay en el campo Cierre pero cogiendo el valor anterior al registro en el que estoy. Aquí os pongo una imagen de los datos de mi tabla y he puesto el campo que me gustaría crear con los datos resultantes a ver si me podriais ayudar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí os pongo el código que estoy utilizando:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'IdActivo': [1,2,3,3,2,1,3],
                   'Fecha' : ['2009-01-01','2009-02-01','2009-02-01','2009-03-01','2009-03-01','2009-03-01','2009-04-01'],
                   'Cierre' : [25.5,26.5,25.8,26.8,24.8,27.5,27.8]})


def Cierre1(df):
    ord_df = df.sort_values(by=['IdActivo', 'Fecha'])
    print(ord_df)


Cierre1(df)
```

He ordenado la tabla por los campos IdActivo y Fecha.

Esperando vuestra respuesta me despido atentamente

Charo

He seguido trabajando en ello y he puesto lo siguiente:

```
def Cierre1(df):
    ord_df = df.sort_values(by=['IdActivo', 'Fecha'])
    ord_df ['Cierre1'] = ord_df.iloc[1:]['Cierre']
    idx = ord_df.iloc[1:]['IdActivo'].values != ord_df.iloc[:len(ord_df) - 1]['IdActivo'].values
    idx = np.append([True], idx)
    ord_df.loc[idx, 'Cierre1'] = np.nan
    print(ord_df)

Cierre1(df)
```

el resultado que me da ahora es el siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Charoeci1, bienvenid@. Puedes sustituir la imagen por texto para mejor lectura, poder copiar/pegar y por si el link se rompe? Gracias

Comment: He probado a poner lo siguiente:def Cierre1(df):
    ord_df = df.sort_values(by=['IdActivo', 'Fecha'])
    ord_df ['Cierre1'] = ord_df.iloc[1:]['Cierre']
    idx = ord_df.iloc[1:]['IdActivo'].values != ord_df.iloc[:len(ord_df) - 1]['IdActivo'].values
    idx = np.append([True], idx)
    ord_df.loc[idx, 'Cierre1'] = np.nan
    print(ord_df)

Cierre1(df)

Comment: Hola, el código que pones sale de [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44874/a%c3%b1adir-columna-a-dataframe-con-una-media-movil-sobre-los-registros-del-mismo). Muy parecido... Deberías leer [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Cuando haces una pregunta, sobre el área de texto tienes una serie de botones para formatear código, etc. Respecto a tu pregunta, para mover los datos de una columna puedes usar el método `shift`. En tu caso podría ser `df.['Cierre1].shift(1)`. Más en los [docs oficiales](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ya he solucionado mi problema. Aquí os digo como lo he hecho.
Me he creado una variable NumIntervalo para poner el número de intervalo que quiero mostrar.
Este es el código:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'IdActivo': [1,2,3,3,2,1,1,3,2],
                   'Fecha' : ['2009-01-01','2009-02-01','2009-02-01','2009-03-01','2009-03-01','2009-03-01','2009-04-01','2009-04-01','2009-04-01'],
                   'Cierre' : [25.5,26.04,88.8,26.8,24.8,27.5,23.05,27.8,30.20]})

NumIntervalo =2 # Me he creado una variable para poner el número de intervalo que quiero mostrar. Así sólo con cambiar el valor aquí no tendré que modificar el procedimiento.

def Cierre1(df,NumIntervalo):
    ord_df = df.sort_values(by=['IdActivo', 'Fecha'])
    ord_df ['Cierre1'] = ord_df['Cierre'].shift(NumIntervalo)
    idx = ord_df.iloc[NumIntervalo:]['IdActivo'].values != ord_df.iloc[:len(ord_df) - NumIntervalo]['IdActivo'].values
    for i in range(NumIntervalo):
        idx = np.append([False], idx)


    ord_df.loc[idx, 'Cierre1'] = np.nan
    print(ord_df)

Cierre1(df,NumIntervalo)
```

Aquí os pongo una imagen con el resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]